# Converting string list to number equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `[['4', '9.012'], ['12', '24.305'], ['20', '20.078']]` .

Now I want to convert it into its number equivalent

```
[[4, 9.012], [12, 24.305], [20, 20.078]]
```

I am new to python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
from ast import literal_eval
newlist = [[literal_eval(el) for el in item] for item in mylist]
```

This way the type will be determined by the type required to hold that number.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's better :p

Comment: Wonderful and best answer

Answer (score 1):

If you always have pairs of integer and float,

```
[[int(x), float(y)] for [x, y] in mylist]
```

Otherwise, for more generality at the expense of type correctness,

```
[[float(x) for x in s] for s in mylist]
```

For more type correctness at the expense of clarity,

```
def number(x): 
  try: 
    return int(x) 
  except: 
    return float(x)
[[number(x) for x in s] for s in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [['4', '9.012'], ['12', '24.305'], ['20', '20.078']]
map(lambda x: [int(x[0]), float(x[1])], lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [['4', '9.012'], ['12', '24.305'], ['20', '20.078']]
>>> l1 = [ [ float(i[0]), float(i[1]) ]    for i in l ]
```

OR

```
>>> l
[['4', '9.012'], ['12', '24.305'], ['20', '20.078']]

>>> def f(arg):
...     return [float(arg[0]), float(arg[1])]

>>> map(f,l)
[[4.0, 9.012], [12.0, 24.305], [20.0, 20.078]]
```